# magento - adding a block using local.xml

Tags: magento, templates, block, php

if I have a template in

```
 app\design\frontend\base\default\template\dir\template.phtml
```

that look like this

```
<div class='block block-list'>  
    <div class='block-title'><strong><span>Some Block</span></strong></div>
        <div class='block-content'>  
            &nbsp;<?php echo "my content"; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
```

How can I show it on a catalog page using local.xml? Shouldn't this code work?

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">    
    <default>                   
       <reference name="right">
         <block  type="core/template" 
            name="somename"
            template="dir/template.phtml" />
      </reference>
    </default>
 </layout>
```

Comment: What do you mean by catalog page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can not have custom layout handle`<catalog_category_default translate="label">` inside default layout handle`<default>`
Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: This is referring to asnwer posted by Palanikumar.

Comment: you seem to be correct. I removed "default' tag and it worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use template reference name before that reference tag.

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
 <layout version="0.1.0">    
    <default>  
     <catalog_category_default translate="label">                 
       <reference name="right">
         <block  type="core/template" 
            name="somename"
            template="dir/template.phtml" />
      </reference>
     </catalog_category_default>
    </default>
 </layout>
```

Comment: you are correct, but as ANKIT pointed out, default tag has to go.